# Partial rollback in function in postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.6

#### Pseudo code

`INSERT INTO table_a
INSERT INTO table_b
RAISE EXCEPTION
UPDATE table_b`

Is there a way to keep the inserted `table_a` tuples but not the `table_b` tuples when this code exists within a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

`DECLARE
  _exception_message text;
  _exception_hint text;
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table_a
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_b
        RAISE EXCEPTION
        UPDATE table_b
        RETURN; 
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS _exception_message = MESSAGE_TEXT, _exception_hint = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
            RETURN; 
    END;
END`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638907/savepoint-in-postgresql-function